# Store a NSOperation with Core Data

Tags: core-data, persistence, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I need to add persistency to an `NSOperationQueue`, so the user can close my application without lose any data.
I'm a big fan of core data, so I'm looking for a way to store my `NSOperation` subclass on core data.

Any advice?

Comment: Sorry, could you explain better what do you want to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: sure, but sorry for my english.
I need to send some information to my server from ipad app, and i create a subclass of NSOperation that perform this job. if user close the app before complete all operations, i need to save them in a persisten way...so i think that coredata can be a good idea. But the question is...can i save an nsoperation inside coredata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your question but I'll try to give you some hints.

Yes, Core Data could be a valid approach to do it. I don't know the reason why you need to store a `NSOperation`.

What I can suggest, instead, is to arrange your model to deal with syncing operations. In particular, I would add an attribute to the entities you need to sync with your sever. Call it , for example, `isSync` and say it's a `BOOL` value.

So, when a specific data is synced with server and you have received a good response, you could just modify that attribute to assume the `YES` value. This means that a specific data has been synced. In other words, when an object (data) is not synced, its `isSync` value is `NO`, otherwise is `YES` and, if you want, you can delete it.

The next time, you can sync data that have `isSync` value to `NO`. They have not been synced yet. Other elements are already synced and you can delete them to save space on your device.

To have an understanding on how syncing can be done, I really suggest to read this stackoverflow topic [How to Sync iPhone Core Data with web server, and then push to other devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035132/how-to-sync-iphone-core-data-with-web-server-and-then-push-to-other-devices).

Furthermore, if you deal with operations, you need to cancel current operations if the user has closed the app. A really interesting discussion can be found in [Queue of NSOperations and handling application exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566230/queue-of-nsoperations-and-handling-application-exit).

Obviously there could be other solutions to achieve this, but I think it could be a simply way to achieve what you want to do.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you for answer. I cannot use only one filed "isSync", because i need to store some other information, like "isUpdated" or "isDeleted".

But thanks for link about nsoperation.